# How to open different activity on click of every individual item on x-axis or y- axis item in bar chart with MPAndroid chart library?

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

In MPAndroid chart library, How to make clickable every individual item in x-axis or y- axis item in bar chart ?

For a Example : if in x axis of bar chart is as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and y axis of bar chart 100,200,300,400,500,600,700

If  click on 1 or 100 it should open one activity,
If click on 2 or 200 it should open another activity and so on ..

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnChartValueSelectedListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            BarChart barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

    barChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false);


            barChart.setDescription("");
            // set xaxis at bottom
            barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            // set xaxis
            barChart.getXAxis().setGridColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
            // set x axis text color
            barChart.getXAxis().setTextColor(Color.argb(42,44,44,44));
           // HorizontalBarChart barChart= (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

            barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
            barChart.setScaleEnabled(false);

            barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
            barChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
            barChart.setDragEnabled(false);
            barChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
            barChart.setScaleXEnabled(false);
            barChart.setScaleYEnabled(false);
            barChart.setPinchZoom(false);
            barChart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(false);
            barChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false);
            barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
            barChart.setGridBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
            barChart.getXAxis().setGridColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
            ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
            entries.add(new BarEntry(100, 0));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(200, 1));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(300, 2));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(400, 3));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(500, 4));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(600, 5));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(700, 6));
            barChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

            BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");

            ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
            labels.add("1");
            labels.add("2");
            labels.add("3");
            labels.add("4");
            labels.add("5");
            labels.add("6");
            labels.add("7");




            BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
            dataset.setColor(Color.rgb(33,200,215));

            barChart.setData(data);
            barChart.animateY(5000);

        }

        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
                startActivity(i);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you check the official documentation about adding events on their charts ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In MPAndroidChart, how to add the click event for the each Bar in Barchart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314966/in-mpandroidchart-how-to-add-the-click-event-for-the-each-bar-in-barchart)

Comment: @AxelH Hey , I don't want to show toast . I want to open different activity(Screen) for a each bar item click ? How it is duplicate ?

Comment: If you can't adapt a code to match your need, this will be complicate for you to write an application. The duplicate give you the solution to add an event listener. Then you just need to write the action that you want (the Intent to start an activitiy).

Comment: @AxelH I have tried to add onValueSelected () with intent to start an activity but it is not going to start second activity when i am clicking x axis or y axis value. also added code.

Comment: Well, here you start the same activity, so don't see the point but you stilll need to identify the activity you want based on the `dataSetIndex`. But once you have click on one, the activity will be stopped to show the new one, so you can't open two activity ... (well you can but it won't show both)

Comment: public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
                startActivity(i);

        }
I am giving like above But on click x or y axis , is not going to Second Activity

Comment: @AxelH could you please tell me how can give condition if clicking on x-axis value while x axis have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h)

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be like this (for an older version of MPAndroidChart):

By `e.getXIndex();` we can find x-Axis index then put condition on it. Every individual item click goes to different activity.

```
@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
    int x = e.getXIndex(); 

    if (x == 0) {
        Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
        startActivity(j);
    }
    else if (x==1) {
        Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Third.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }
    else if (x==2) {
        Intent k= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fourth.class);
        startActivity(k);
    }
    else if (x==3) {
        Intent k1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fifth.class);
        startActivity(k1);
    }
    else if (x==4) {
        Intent k2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sixth.class);
        startActivity(k2);
    }
    else if (x==5) {
        Intent k3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Seventh.class);
        startActivity(k3);
    }
    else if (x==6) {
        Intent k4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Eight.class);
        startActivity(k4);
    }
}
```

Comment: I formatted your answer for you and added a note about the older version of MPAndroidChart

Answer (score 0):

Please spend some time reading the [wiki](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki) and javadoc for MPAndroidChart to understand the basic concepts. Remember, you can use <kbd>Ctr-Q</kbd> on PC or <kbd>Cmd-J</kbd> on Mac to get the tooltip for the the class you have the cursor on in Android Studio.

The solution in MPAndroidChart 3.0.2 looks something like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
        float x = e.getX(); //get the x value
        int roundedX = (int) Math.round(x); //round it to an integer
        Intent nextActivity;
        if (roundedX == 1) {
            nextActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(nextActivity);
        }
    }
```

A smarter solution would store the class objects in an array or list rather than use conditionals but it's best to attempt the simple first. Please spend some more time learning the basic concepts in Java and Android otherwise you will find it very hard to make progress.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time ,answer and suggestion . But
float x = e.getX(); is not working in this case. and it is not going to next activity .

Comment: How is it not working? Also you shoukd probably delete the duplicate question or people will downvote it!

Comment: I think maybe you are using an older version of MPAndroidChart. Which version are you using? Also remember you need to set the listener `barChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this)`

Comment: I am not afraid to downvote or upvote . I was facing problem & got solution. Thank you so much . and i am not going to delete question.